# sump pump is 5ft deep with surface grade crawlspace, its pumping water more frequently than I like. Should I raise the pump?

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

This pump seems to always pump, even weeks after storms, though at lower frequency. I measured, water seem to be coming in at about 4ft under the ground from the holes drilled in the basin.

If my crawlspace foundation is at surface level, is the sump pump dug in too deep? I dont like how often its cycling the pump, and it seems like its pointlessly doing this work, if the groundwater eventually recedes.

Answer (score 1):

You raise the level of the float trigger, not the pump, to reduce the frequency. If you are OK with having a high water table under your foundation, you could also raise the pump intake. You won't know the actual height of the water table unless you turn the pump off long enough for the water height to stabilize.

Comment: theres holes cut into the sump pit at various heights. usually i see water coming through from 4ft and below. And the water pit fills up maybe 6inches before it pumps. I just dont know if I am digging in too deep here and pumping all this for no reason with this much gap(4ft between crawlspace floor and water table).